# RTSP stream is not accessible when using static IP?

Tags: android, networking, ip, vlc, rtsp

**My goal**: To check RTSP stream latency from peer-2-peer (from an android device to a PC) connected to each other via a LAN cable.

**What I am doing**: Steps a follows

**1) Setting up static IP on my PC with following credentials**

IP: 192.168.1.2

Netmask: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: 192.168.1.2

**2) Setting up static IP on my hardware running android (using this [link](http://www.biemmeitalia.net/blog/android-network-configuration/)) with following credentials**

IP: 192.168.1.3

Netmask: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: 192.168.1.2

DNS1: 8.8.8.8

DNS2: 4.4.4.4

**[NOTE: Both my PC and the android device is connected with each other via a LAN cable]**

**3) Run an app to generate a RTSP camera stream from the android device**

I am using [RTSP Camera Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miv.rtspcamera&hl=en) on my android device.

**4) Play the RTSP stream on my PC using VLC**

```
$ vlc rtsp://192.168.1.3:5554/camera
VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (revision 2.2.1~trusty2)
[0000000001e12118] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00007f1478000e38] live555 demux error: Failed to connect with rtsp://192.168.1.3:5554/camera
```

NOTE: Everything above works fine if I use dynamic IP on both ***my PC*** and ***the android device*** in an internal network,  where both are connected to the internal network via a network switch.

[Update] I have searched many forums and blogs but haven't seen anyone having problem with RTSP once the link between two peers are establishes successfully. My both peers (the PC and the android device) can ping each other when using static IP. I have tried different app for RTSP streaming but I got the same result.

[Update] I have connected my android device with my pc via USB. Switch on the USB tethering on android device. So both pc and android device are in peer-2-peer connection. It worked. I am able to see RTSP stream on vlc in my PC. If USB tethering donot work try the below command on an adb shell.

```
# setprop persist.sys.usb.config.extra none
```

[Update] Connecting the PC and the android device to a router (which is not connected to internet) I established a so called peer-2-peer connection between them. I was able to capture the RTPS stream (from android device) on VLC on the PC.

**So why does the RTSP stream is not capture on PC using VLC when am connecting the two devices directly via a LAN cable ?**

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you telnet to your RTSP server port from your RTSP client device? If not, please check the RTSP server side first.